# My m.2 drive not seen in BIOS

Tags: bios

I cant see my new Samsung NVMe SSD 960 EVO m.2 drive in my BIOS. Motherboard is HP Pavilion Gaming Notebook, motherboard is 80A9 91.1E, BIOS F.85. Can anyone help, PLEASE?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you checked for an updated BIOS? Have you reset the BIOS settings? We'd like to help, but simply telling us it doesn't work isn't giving us enough information to allow us to help you. Please use the EDIT button to add any and all relevant and helpful information to your question.

Comment: For instance, on my desktops, I have to change around PCI settings ... deactivate some PCI slots in order for the m2 slot to work.